# ng-table - unable to populate select dropdown

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngtable

Why isn't this working? I'm using a "Custom dropdown filter" from [example number 11](http://bazalt-cms.com/ng-table/example/11) on the ng-table website. They show how to get a dropdown working with **static** data, whereas I need it to work with an API call.

Of note: In the example, they're using a function (which must be an $q promise):

```
filter-data="names($column)"
```

As of [ng-table v0.4.3](https://github.com/esvit/ng-table/releases/tag/v0.4.3), you can now just return static data, by pointing to a $scope variable:

```
filter-data="someScopeVariable"
```

**The problem:**

I can see the data if I print it to the view as `[{"id":1111,"title":1111}, ...]`, but not in the ng-table dropdown.

In my controller:

```
$scope.initNgTableData = $q.all([MyDataService.getMyData().$promise])
           .then( function(result) {
            var arr = [],
            names = [];
            data = result[0];
            angular.forEach(data.items, function(item){
                if (inArray(result[0], arr) === -1) {
                    arr.push(item.vlan);
                    names.push({
                        'id': item.vlan,
                        'title': item.vlan
                    });
                }
            });
            $scope.ngtableMyData = names;
            return $scope.ngtableMyData;

           });
```

I've tried both methods to get the data:

#1 a scope.data variable **$scope.ngtableMyData** which resolves to an array:

And in my view I've tried getting plain data:

```
<td class="col-md-1" data-title="'FOO'" filter="{ 'foo': 'select' }" filter-data="$scope.ngtableMyData" sortable="'foo'">
            ...
        </td>
```

#2  I've also tried tried using a function to get the resolved promise **$scope.initNgTableData()**:

```
<td class="col-md-1" data-title="'FOO'" filter="{ 'foo': 'select' }" filter-data="$scope.initNgTableData()" sortable="'foo'">
        ...        </td>
```

I feel like the problem is related to the asynchronous nature of an API.

**Note**:
You can't just point it to any JSON array. The data returned must be an array with an "id", and "title". See the example I linked above (Example 11) to see how they shape the return data.

You can try modifying this Plunker with an API call http://plnkr.co/edit/wKgf04
(Please note, I'm using $resource and not $http).

Comment: What exactly is not working in that plnker?  It is unclear as it seems to work fine.

Comment: That plnkr uses data, not an API call. I'm having problems using an Angular $resource. I'm basically using that plunker, but with the controller code in my question.